# Installing PyLucene on a Mac

Tags: macos, pylucene, jcc

I would like to be able to use pyLucene on my Mac. The instructions have me hopelessly lost because each instruction for setting up or making requires that I do something before it, and it's hard to know where to start and what to do from what window.

I have downloaded PyLucene.  The first thing I'm wondering is where I put the folder, since that doesn't seem self-evident to me.

To use it, I am told I need to build JCC, which is included in the pylucene download.

The instructions:

> At the command line, enter:
>
> ```
> $ python setup.py build
> $ sudo python setup.py install
> ```

But to do this, I think, I need to be in the right place or put the folder in the right place because otherwise I'm getting `"setup.py" not found`.

Any help you can offer on this environment (A shell window? An IDE?). Any help on getting pas this first part: building JCC, followed by setting up pylucene is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

This works on recent macOS versions. First, make sure you install:

- [Java Development Kit 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- [Java 1.6 from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US) (due to a bug)
- Apache Ant, ideally with Homebrew and `brew install ant --with-ivy`

Then add to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Then, reload your shell.

[Download PyLucene](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/lucene/pylucene/) and extract the folder, `cd` to it from your shell. Now, follow the instructions from the [official installation guide](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html):

```
cd jcc
python setup.py build
```

Now, install JCC:

```
python setup.py install
```

(A `sudo` may be required if you are using the macOS system Python.)

Now go back to the parent folder and edit the `Makefile`. Replace the uncommented lines as instructed with the actual path to `ant`, `python`, `jcc`, and the `NUM_FILES`:

```
ANT=ant
PYTHON=python
JCC=python -m jcc
NUM_FILES=8
```

Now build PyLucene:

```
make
make test
```

Finally, to install the built PyLucene:

```
make install
```

(You may need `sudo` if using the system Python.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! that works perfectly!. Will surely try out things next time!

Answer (score 3):

Download pre-built JCC and pylucene eggs for Mac from [here](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/pylucene-extra/downloads/list?q=mac).

As of now, the latest versions are JCC-2.8 and lucene-3.1.0 for python 2.6, so below I'll use easy_install-2.6 and python2.6.

Install them:

```
$ sudo easy_install-2.6 JCC-*.egg
$ sudo easy_install-2.6 lucene-*.egg
```

Test:

```
$ python2.6
>>> import jcc
>>> import lucene
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lucene-3.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lucene/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _lucene
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lucene-3.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lucene/_lucene.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjcc.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lucene-3.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lucene/_lucene.so
  Reason: image not found
```

If you get the above error, fix it by simply creating symlink of `libjcc.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib/`. `libjcc.dylib` should be inside `site-packages/JCC-*.egg/`.

```
>>> jcc.__file__
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/JCC-2.8-py2.6-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/jcc/__init__.pyc'
>>> ^D

$ ln -s /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/JCC-2.8-py2.6-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/libjcc.dylib /usr/local/lib/

$ python2.6
>>> import jcc, lucene
>>>
```

Comment: This worked for me!  The combination of special versions and symlinks was not obvious at all, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Tarun See my answer below, I just followed the official guide.